# Recycler View not showing in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have three fragments: *Fragment user*, *Fragment Home* and *Fragment Progress*.

I'm trying to implement a recylcer view in the homefragment that can recycle images in the recycler view nothing is happening and no error is showing in logcat, i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

1.This is my Custom Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
@NonNull

private LayoutInflater inflator;
List<Information> data= Collections.emptyList();

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
    inflator= LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflator.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Information current=data.get(position);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.images);
    holder.title.setText(current.title);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView icon;
    TextView title;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listicon);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
}
```

2. This is my Fragment

   ```
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
   import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
   import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
   import android.widget.ImageView;
   import android.widget.ListView;
   import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.List;
   public class HomeFragment extends Fragment  {
   private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
   private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
   private CustomAdapter adapter;
   int[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.abs,R.drawable.arms,R.drawable.back,R.drawable.chest,R.drawable.full,R.drawable.legs};
   private RecyclerView recyclerView;


   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;


   private String mParam1;
   private String mParam2;


   public HomeFragment() {

     }
   public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {                   
   HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
   args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
   fragment.setArguments(args);
   return fragment;
       }
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if (getArguments() != null) {
       mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
       mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
   }
       }
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    recyclerView =(RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
   return layout;
     }

   public static List<Information> getData(){
   List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
   int [] icons = {R.drawable.abs,R.drawable.arms,R.drawable.back,R.drawable.chest,R.drawable.full,R.drawable.legs};
   String[] titles={"Abs","Arms","Back","Chest","full","legs"};
   for (int i=0; i<icons.length && i<titles.length;i++){

       Information current = new Information();
       current.images=icons[i];
       current.title=titles[i];
       data.add(current);
   }
   return data;

   }





   }
   ```

I can't see to find what I'm doing wrong.

1. fragmenthome.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".HomeFragment">



   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/drawerList"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </FrameLayout>
   ```

4.Custom_layout.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listicon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: share your layout as well

Comment: why item count is 0 in your adapter file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didnt assign the data in your adapter's constructor

```
this.data = data;
```

then your item count should be

```
  data.size();
```

should not be 0.

Comment: Thanks that worked out , but there is a space between the images , one image is showing in one page ,have to scroll down furthur to view other

Comment: That's because you have "match_parent" on both attributes. Try using "wrap_content" on the root RelativeLayout of your Custom_layout.xml

Comment: I only have match parent for width , wrap content for height

Comment: make wrap content to  the recyclerview

Comment: It worked but when i scrolled down and scrolled back up it was back to same again 
please see the images
https://ibb.co/jXgXU9
https://ibb.co/ceTCU9

Comment: make your relativelayout as wrap_content